# WebUSB access mass storage USB serial number

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, usb, webusb

I am trying to **access a USB mass storage device using the WebUSB interface**. I have read that USB mass storage devices cannot be accessed:

- "For example, if the device is a USB mass storage device that
  interface is not claimable and if there are no other interfaces the
  device will be hidden." ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67271630/3691763))
- "The following set of USB interface classes, which should not be claimed using the WebUSB API, will be explicitly blocked by Blink: Audio, Video, HID, Mass Storage[...]" ([Link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/LZXocaeCwDw/m/GLfAffGLAAAJ?pli=1))
- "It cannot. USB mass storage devices are claimed by the system's generic USB mass storage class driver and are therefore unavailable to the browser." ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49177503/3691763))

We are currently using usb sticks for a standalone version of the app where the serial number of the usb stick is important to identify the license. For our new software I also need to access the serial number of the usb mass storage device, but best would be if I could do so in the browser.

**Google Chrome does recognise the device** as can be seen here.

[image: Chrome is recognizing the device]

But when asking for **access to a device via WebUSB it is not shown in the list**:
[image]

My code is pretty straight forward:

```
navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [] }).then(e => {console.log(e)});
```

Is there any way to **access the serial number of the USB mass storage device** using a browser interface?

Comment: thanks but as mentioned the usb device is not listed, thus USBDevice.serialNumber cannot be accessed.

Comment: Looks like mass storage devices are only available via the [WebHID API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebHID_API). But a `HIDDevice` has no serial number -> [Serial number · Issue #34 · WICG/webhid · GitHub](https://github.com/WICG/webhid/issues/34)

Comment: Unfortunately also when using HID the device is not recognized... (and of course the serial number problem is still there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The internal page `about:usb-internals` should show you interfaces that are blocked in WebUSB. As you can see in the screenshot below, "Mass Storage" USB devices are indeed not accessible in WebUSB for security reasons.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is there a way to unblock them?